# copying sheets from multiple workbooks to existing workbook- VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, path, worksheet

I am trying to copy 4 sheets from 4 different workbooks into the 'Master' workbook that I am in

The below code just does it for one sheet but I want to do it for all 4 sheets

Also, currently the code below opens up the source sheet but I don't want to open source sheets. If I remove '.Open" from below file path then it says subscript out of range

Thanks

```
Sub Copysheets()

Dim source As Workbook
Dim Master As Workbook

Set source = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsx")
Set Master = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsm")

Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet

For Each sourcesheet In source.Sheets

sourcesheet.Copy After:=Master.Sheets(Master.Sheets.Count)
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a task that you need to do repeated times, usually it's a good idea outsource the task to a subroutine.

The following routine gets 2 parameters, the first is the master (the workbook where you want to copy the sheets into) and a filename (with the name of the file to be opened and copied). This copy-routine doesn't care about your business logic, it simply copies the sheets:

```
Sub Copysheets(masterWB As Workbook, sourceWBName As String)
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook, sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(sourceWBName)

    For Each sourceSheet In sourceWB.Sheets
        sourceSheet.Copy After:=masterWB.Sheets(masterWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next
    ' Don't forget to close the file afterwards:
    sourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

You could then call the the routine like this (this piece of code handles your business logic but doesn't care about how the copy is done):

```
Sub CopySheetsFrom4Workbooks()
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsm")
    
    Copysheets masterWB, "\\filepath\filename1.xlst"
    Copysheets masterWB, "\\filepath\filename2.xlst"
    Copysheets masterWB, "\\filepath\filename3.xlst"
    Copysheets masterWB, "\\filepath\filename4.xlst"

    masterWB.Save
End Sub
```

or, for example, use a loop to copy sheets of all files:

```
Sub CopyAllMyWorkbooks()
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsm")
    
    Dim sourceFilename As String
    sourceFilename = Dir("\\filepath\filename*.xlst")
    Do While sourceFilename <> ""
        Copysheets masterWB, sourceFilename
        sourceFilename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not able to run the first subroutine you created. I can't find it in the list of macros. Also, when running the 2nd sub-routine I get a run-time error '91' object variable not set on masterWB = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsm")

Comment: Have you put the code into a regular module? It will not be displayed when you put it into the Workbook- or Worksheet module

Comment: what do you mean by regular module ? I just put into the vba module as a sub like any other sub. I probably misunderstand you

Comment: You have a Workbook module and one worksheet module for every Workbook in VBA. Usually you put event code into those. If you want to use macros that you can call for example from Excel Developer Tab, you need to create a "regular" module (in VBA, Project explorer, right click and select "Insert"->"Module"

Comment: Hey, thanks for your support again. Did you manage to understand why I get a "run-time error '91' object variable not set" on the following line of code: masterWB = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsm")

Comment: Sorry, my fault: A workbook is an *object*, and in VBA you need to use `Set` to assign an object to a variable: `Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(...)`. Code corrected.

Comment: thanks again. The last issue I am having is that your 'copysheets' sub is asking for a file     Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\filename.xlsx")
but the sheets I want to pull are from multiple files not just one file

Comment: Have a look to the 2 subs at the bottom. One is calling the copy routine for 4 hardcoded files, the other for all excel files in a folder. Just take the one that fits better for your needs and adapt it to your actual file/folder names.

Comment: My questions and the error is about the first sub not the 2nd or 3rd sub. you need the first sub (Copysheets) to be able to run the code

Comment: Upps, sorry, that was a cut&paste problem from my test code. The hardcoded filename in that routine of course made no sense. Corrected.

Comment: makes sense now. thanks a lot. I ticked your answer